# how to define global variable and use case statements in functions?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to declare two global variables in php like below

```
<?php
$a = "Nvalamap";
$b="Bvalamap";
?>
```

And want to use these variable in second file where javascript function define

```
<script> 
function drawMapFromWms(latt,longt,complaintid){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "tools/nrega_v2.1/map.php",
    data: 'complaintid='+complaintid,
    success: function(data){         
      var data_array = JSON.parse(data);


  $('.modal-info').html("");

  var hrymap='<div id="hrymap"></div>';
    $(".modal-info").append(hrymap);

  $('#hrymap').html(""); 

    $('#hrymap').html("<div id='map' style='width:850px;height:650px;'></div>");
          var map = L.map('map');

setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize(true)}, 300);

//map.setView([29.0, 76.776695], 8);
map.setView([29.0, 76.776695], 8);
map.fitBounds([
  [latt,longt]

]);

                 L.tileLayer.wms("<?php echo $basemap; ?>", {
             layers:'india3',

       format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
       attribution:"Indian Remote Sensing Satellites"
        //attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
    }).addTo(map);

          L.tileLayer.wms("<?php echo $roadmap; ?>", {
             layers:'hrcm_roads',

       format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
       attribution:"text"
          }).addTo(map);

     var marker = L.marker([latt,longt]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Complaint ID:'+data_array.complaint_id+'</br>Road ID:'+data_array.road_id+'</br>Complainant Name:'+data_array.name+'</br>Complaint Type:'+data_array.feedback_type)
    .openPopup();
     map.invalidateSize();

     $("#detail_content").css({'display':'block'});


    }
  });

  }
/***********second function same but basemap and roadmap is differnt*****/
function drawMapFromWms(latt,longt,complaintid){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "tools/nrega_v2.1/map.php",
    data: 'complaintid='+complaintid,
    success: function(data){         
      var data_array = JSON.parse(data);


  $('.modal-info').html("");

  var hrymap='<div id="hrymap"></div>';
    $(".modal-info").append(hrymap);

  $('#hrymap').html(""); 

    $('#hrymap').html("<div id='map' style='width:850px;height:650px;'></div>");
         var map;

      require([
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/graphic", 
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, GraphicsLayer,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
      ) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "<?php echo $basemap; ?>",
          center: [76.0856,29.0588],
          zoom: 10
        });
        map.on("load", function() {
          var gl = new GraphicsLayer();
          var p = new Point(76.0856,29.0588);
          var s = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(60);
          var g = new Graphic(p, s);
          gl.add(g);
          map.addLayer(gl);
          map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer('<?php echo $roadmap; ?>'));
        });
      });

     $("#detail_content").css({'display':'block'});


    }
  });

  }

</script>
```

I want one onclick="drawMapFromWms(latt,longt,complaintid);" function call then it will run according to case parameters if $a have some value then first function call in second case if $b have some value then second function call both function have same name but working is different

Comment: onclick="drawMapFromWms(<?= $lat?>,<?= $longt?>,<?= $complaintid?>);"

Comment: i want if drawMapFromWms function call it will call according to the value of global variable if $a have value then first function call otherwise second call actually i need a case statement with functions

Comment: Javascript knows nothing of php and vice versa.

Comment: means there is no way to define case statement in javascript?

Comment: There is the switch/case commands in Javascript. You haven't provided and real information on how you want this to be done (the information that you have provided is either incorrect or irrelevant).

Comment: First i have to define the above function in two way first according to the first case when $a have some value and second case i need to define the function when $b have some value

Comment: As I said, you have not provided enough code to help so giving assistance is not possible to write all the variations that is possible to what you want to achieve.

Comment: how can i provide the code because i don't know how to write the functions in switch cases in javascript i already provide the two functions what else you needed i don't know

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP variables are created on the server side but the Javascript part is executed on the client so you need to offer the client a way to access these variables within its scope. One way would be to output the values for your `$a` and `$b` in a Javascript block and assign them to the `window` scope (which is quite close to a global JS variable).

```
<script>
window.a = '<?php print $a; ?>';
window.b = '<?php print $b; ?>';
</script>
```

As the code is rendered on the server-side and will then be sent to the client, this will equal:

```
<script>
window.a = 'Nvalamap';
window.b = 'Bvalamap';
</script>
```

(Assuming you set `$a = 'Nvalamap';`, `$b= 'Bvalamap';` before rendering).

Now to the second part of your question:

> I want one onclick="drawMapFromWms(latt,longt,complaintid);" function
>   call then it will run according to case parameters if $a have some
>   value then first function call in second case if $b have some value
>   then second function call both function have same name but working is
>   different.

IMO it is bad coding practice to have two functions with the same name but with different functionality as this might cause confusion when the same function behaves differently. I would recommend to have one function that decides which way to take based on the provided inputs or variables. To stick to the first part of this example:

```
<script>
function drawMapFromWms(latt,longt,complaintid)
{
  if (window.a !== '') {
    handlerForVariableA(latt, longt, complaintid);
  } else {
    handlerForVariableB(latt, longt, complaintid);
  }
}

function handlerForVariableA (latt, longt, complaintid)
{
  // execute code that is relevant when "$a" was set on the server-side. 
}

function handlerForVariableB (latt, longt, complaintid)
{
  // execute code that is relevant when "$b" was set on the server-side. 
}
</script>
```